# If $f(x),g(x)$ are two differentiable functions such that $f'(x)=g(x)$, $|f(x)|<1$ and $f(0)^2+g(0)^2=9$

Tags: calculus, functions

> If $f(x),g(x)$ are two differentiable functions such that $f'(x)=g(x)$, $|f(x)|<1$ and $f(0)^2+g(0)^2=9$, prove that there exists a $c\in(-3,3)$ such that $g(c)\cdot g''(c)<0$

$$f(0)^2+g(0)^2=9$$
Using the above equation, $g(0)\in (-3,-2\sqrt{2})\cup(2\sqrt{2},3)$

That's how much I was able to solve. I only have information about the value of functions at $x=0$.

Comment: So, $g$ is twice differentiable?

Comment: Possible hint: assume for contradiction that g(c)*g''(c) <= 0 for all c in (-3,3). In particular, this means g(c) and g''(c) have opposite signs (unless one of them happens to be 0 at a given point). Not sure if this will help, but it may.

Comment: These sure look like scaled sin and cos.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1305612/72031

Comment: are you sure the conclusion is $g(c)g''(c) > 0$ and not $g(c)g''(c) < 0$ as mentioned in linked question.

Comment: So this question already has an answer.